# twig slice filter on object print Array

Tags: twig

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html

```
{% set varTest = 'azertyuiop' %}
{{ varTest[:2] }} {# show 'az' #}
```

but on an object as `{{ myObj.name[:2] }}` result is Array !

is-it the filter limit ?

Comment: Your class needs to implement [traversable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php). Otherwise twigs slice method will not work correct.

Comment: what does `myObj.name` return? I guess if `myObj` is an object there should be a method named `name` otherwise if it's array I suggest to use `myObj['name'][:2]`

Comment: myObj.name return a string